# How to define Typescript type as a dictionary of strings but with one numeric "id" property

Tags: typescript

My existing JavaScript code has "records" where the id is numeric and the other attributes are strings. I'm trying to define this type:

```
type T = {
    id: number;
    [key: string]: string
}
```

but I get error 2411: `Property 'id' of type 'number' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'string'.`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There is no specific type in TypeScript that corresponds to your desired structure.  String [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) must apply to *every* property, even the manually declared ones like `id`.  What you're looking for is something like a "rest index signature" or a "default property type", and there is an open suggestion in GitHub asking for this: [microsoft/TypeScript#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867).  A while ago there was some work done that would have enabled this, but it was shelved (see [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867#issuecomment-547940152) for more info).  So it's not clear when or if this will happen.

---

You could widen the type of the index signature property so it includes the hardcoded properties via a union, like

```
type WidenedT = {
    id: number;
    [key: string]: string | number
}
```

but then you'd have to test every dynamic property before you could treat it as a `string`:

```
function processWidenedT(t: WidenedT) {
    t.id.toFixed(); // okay
    t.random.toUpperCase(); // error
    if (typeof t.random === "string") t.random.toUpperCase(); // okay
}
```

---

The *best* way to proceed here would be if you could refactor your JavaScript so that it doesn't "mix" the `string`-valued bag of properties with a `number`-valued `id`.  For example:

```
type RefactoredT = {
    id: number;
    props: { [k: string]: string };
}
```

Here `id` and `props` are completely separate and you don't have to do any complicated type logic to figure out whether your properties are `number` or `string` valued.  But this would require a bunch of changes to your existing JavaScript and might not be feasible.

From here on out I'll assume you can't refactor your JavaScript. But notice how clean the above is compared to the messy stuff that's coming up:

---

One common workaround to the lack of rest index signatures is to use an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) to get around the constraint that index signatures must apply to every property:

```
type IntersectionT = {
    id: number;
} & { [k: string]: string };
```

It sort of kind of works; when given a value of type `IntersectionT`, the compiler sees the `id` property as a `number` and any other property as a `string`:

```
function processT(t: IntersectionT) {
    t.id.toFixed(); // okay
    t.random.toUpperCase(); // okay
    t.id = 1; // okay
    t.random = "hello"; // okay
}
```

But it's not really type safe, since you are technically claiming that `id` is both a `number` (according to the first intersection member) and a `string` (according to the second intersection member).  And so you unfortunately can't assign an object literal to that type without the compiler complaining:

```
t = { id: 1, random: "hello" }; // error!
// Property 'id' is incompatible with index signature.
```

You have to work around that further by doing something like [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
const propBag: { [k: string]: string } = { random: "" };
t = Object.assign({ id: 1 }, propBag);
```

But this is annoying, since most users will never think to synthesize an object in such a roundabout way.

---

A different approach is to use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type to represent your type instead of a specific type.  Think of writing a type *checker* that takes as input a *candidate* type, and returns something compatible if and only if that candidate type matches your desired structure:

```
type VerifyT<T> = { id: number } & { [K in keyof T]: K extends "id" ? unknown : string };
```

This will require a generic helper function so you can infer the generic `T` type, like this:

```
const asT = <T extends VerifyT<T>>(t: T) => t;
```

Now the compiler will allow you to use object literals and it will check them the way you expect:

```
asT({ id: 1, random: "hello" }); // okay
asT({ id: "hello" }); // error! string is not number
asT({ id: 1, random: 2 }); // error!  number is not string
asT({ id: 1, random: "", thing: "", thang: "" }); // okay
```

It's a little harder to *read* a value of this type with unknown keys, though.  The `id` property is fine, but other properties will not be known to exist, and you'll get an error:

```
function processT2<T extends VerifyT<T>>(t: T) {
    t.id.toFixed(); // okay
    t.random.toUpperCase(); // error! random not known to be a property
}
```

---

Finally, you can use a hybrid approach that combines the best aspects of the intersection and generic types.  Use the generic type to create values, and the intersection type to read them:

```
function processT3<T extends VerifyT<T>>(t: T): void;
function processT3(t: IntersectionT): void {
    t.id.toFixed();
    if ("random" in t)
        t.random.toUpperCase(); // okay
}
processT3({ id: 1, random: "hello" });
```

The above is an [overloaded](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) function, where *callers* see the generic type, but the *implementation* sees the intersection type.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgLgngDgpgBGOBeOBvAsAKDjuBLAEwC44A7AVwFsAjGAJwG4tc4BtAaxghIGcw68pAOYBdXv0FCsAXxDAsWSLDgB1QjFIwCAFWRpmuQiQo16TbLg5dxA4WLh9bQuAB8yVWnRkLMS+ACUYADMAQwBjMAB7Oi1dFAwLHCN3U0YDHCg6SKgeElQ2dhtJe0dJOGlzaR8-OABJUjB6HhgIvEjSOP1E-GIUz0q4ADI0AqK7MecKnyDyUlb2uEzIsJgeHm0ACjASesa6ZvmOgEouljAAOkJzqIAxPAAPLQ2jhjhgYDhI9hCIdIRzughUgESKUa6RACqUFgdAAwiFms9Xu9Pt9ft0LoQ9ABGZEfL4-P4XQHA0F6ABEAAsYAAbGmRcl41GEzBEvT5ZLYgA0cBJIMoJCptPp5PKTPoWToAEI-iiAApZGGQOAAckIKvwPHwc1BUBCYDw1Bp8AA7ngwJTtQQYPcHHghKR9eQYucfCwwu0+ItFQAhEJCPKjBwScbBpzldm8oH8wWiqYYvQAeWoACsWhcETx7aQNhzetjyjyllA-UIXt5Wb5oPAAGr0PBBCDaAA82gAfJHkiZPBHhvlWABpbVwTgQSJBODaexDm2NYFa8mEUUAfjgs3YpEiJtIcAmYp8HtIXoRnVbcFnGgIWrrAkbLfbba2JG0JyQHbA5iwJ9zPRI3KjpICnAQp0gy5QvG8+JonAX7rD+yQgSK4HinQkpSmGZR4Fqm6IN29CwZseZ-jyfKgiQABMyGQeeqHROhfT0JqZCRIgpTCAR8H5iR0ZkcB5I8hakixgJlJAgGfFUSiBLolgMxzAaCxLCsazaORZ4XvOcA3g2Tatm2j7bJOJwJGclwEOCdyPAQSLUdJRIAjxYJRFCMLwoiEEohKdEAfyzGIBuW47lEcC0HAITetk9CQBWsmzIcEXKesADM6n3HOV5afWd56QZz5HCQABukSEOYcnxUpqzJU+dQNE06ZtMchXFQQpy4Ji5m3A8Tzlt0DZwBs5KkZQoqCAgRx-KZQ3gi59BuTANlSWiFYVSpSWccRPm8YhYHSD1QA)

Comment: Great answer thanks. Can't be more complete and is also very informative, kind of mini advanced Typescript course. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Very clever. I knew that there should be function helper but I would never come up to merge [unknown] type with [number]

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error since you have declared it as Indexable Type (ref: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) with string being the key type, so `id` being a number fails to conform to that declaration.

It is difficult to guess your intention here, but may be you wanted something like this:

```
class t {
  id: number;
  values = new Map<string, string>();
}
```

Comment: Yes "descending" the values of one level would be a perfect solution for _new_ code but unfortunately not applicable here. See answer from jcalz, very complete and informative.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, but returned the id as a string.

```
export type Party = { [key: string]: string }
```

I preferred to have a flat type and parseInt(id) on the receiving code.

For my API, the simplest thing that could possibly work.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a type having dynamic keys containing object as value. I am writing an example here and you can modify it later for your use case,

Please have a look at the definition and usage of the example mentioned below:

```ts
//DEFINE TYPE
type MyObject = {
  [key: string]: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    // ... other properties
  };
};

// EXAMPLE USAGE
const myDynamicObject: MyObject = {
  key1: {
    id: 1,
    name: "ABC",
    
  },
  key2: {
    id: 2,
    name: "DEF",
    
  },
  // ... other dynamic keys and values
};

// PRINTING OBJECT IN CONSOLE LOG
console.log(JSON.stringify(myDynamicObject));
```