# Typescript Interface with unknown key name

Tags: typescript, types, interface, typing

Im trying to create an interface in Typescript which has an both Unkown key names and known key names. Something like this:

```
interface Data { 
    test: string,
    [key: string]: string,
    foo?: boolean,
}
```

So that im able to do this:

```
x: Data = {
  test: "test_string",
  "unknown_key": "value"
}
```

Anyone know how im able to do this? Thanks.

Comment: The possible types of `[key: string]` must cover the types of all the other properties, so in your case `[key: string]: string | boolean | undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by combining the custom fields with [`Record<string, string>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype):

```
type Data = Record<string, string> & { 
  test: string;
  foo?: boolean;
}
```

Comment: THis solution is not type safe, because you can still use `string` for `foo` key

Answer (score -1):

Here you have an example:

```
// You can omit `test` property in Data interface since it has a string type
interface Data { 
    [key: string]: string,
    foo?: boolean,
}

// You can use Verify helper instead of Data interface. It is almost the same
type VerifyT<T> = { foo?: boolean } & { [K in keyof T]: K extends "foo" ? unknown : string };

const make = <T extends VerifyT<T>>(t: T) => t;
make({ age: 'sdf', foo: true }) // Ok
make({ age: 'sdf', foo: undefined }) // ok
make({ age: 'sdf', foo: undefined }) // false
make({ age: 'sdf', foo: 'some text' }) // error
make({ age: 'sdf', foo: 1 }) // error
make({ age: 'sdf', foo: [1] }) // error
```

Don't worry about function overhead, because if you use V8 engine, it will be 99% inlined and optimized

All gredits goes to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431397/how-to-define-typescript-type-with-numeric-id-and-string-value) answer.

Also feel free to marks this question as a dublicate