# Multiple indexer in Indexable types in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, interface

I was reading [Indexable Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) in TypeScript. I was going through this example.

```
interface Animal {
  name: string;
}

interface Dog extends Animal {
  breed: string;
}

// Error: indexing with a numeric string might get you a completely separate type of Animal!
interface NotOkay {
  [x: number]: Animal;
// Numeric index type 'Animal' is not assignable to string index type 'Dog'.
  [x: string]: Dog;
}
```

I am not able to swallow why the above code will create a problem. I went through many articles online but to no avail. Can anyone explain me in simple words with at least an example how above code will create a problem while doing this won't.

```
interface Okay {
      [x: string]: Dog;
      [x: number]: Animal;
}
```

It will be much appreciated if correlation with languages like C++, Java (superclass, subclass) is made here too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR:

- Objects in JS/TS don't really have keys of type `number`; they are actually a special type of `string` keys.
- Index signatures in TS cannot conflict with other index signatures or properties.
- Since a "`number`" key is actually a special kind of `string` key, any `number` index signature property must be assignable to a `string` index signature property if it exists.

---

One possibly confusing issue is that JavaScript doesn't have truly numeric keys; keys in JavaScript are either `symbol`s or `string`s... even for something like arrays which are usually thought of as having numeric indices.

When you index into an object with a key of any type other than `symbol`, JS will *coerce it to a `string`* if it isn't already one.  So while you can think of a one-element array of having an element at index `0`, it's more technically correct to say it has an element at index `"0"`:

```
const arr: [string] = [""];
const arrKeys: string[] = Object.keys(arr);
console.log(arrKeys) // ["0"]
console.log(arrKeys.includes(0 as any)) // false
console.log(arrKeys.includes("0")) // true
arr[0] = "foo";
arr["0"] = "bar";
console.log(arr[0]); // "bar";
```

TypeScript allows you to specify an index signature of key type `number` to represent array-like element access, but it doesn't change the fact that numeric keys are coerced to strings.  It would be more accurate if the `number` index signature used a type like `NumericString` instead.  But there is no such type exposed in TypeScript. (Aside: well, TypeScript 4.1's [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) actually give you a way to represent such a type as

```
type NumericString = `${number}`;
```

but it didn't exist when numeric index signatures were added.)  So while in general `number` is not a subtype of `string`, for *keys*, you can think of `number` as a type of `string`.

---

The next possible point of confusion is that TypeScript doesn't view index signatures as an "exception".  If you add an index signature, it must not conflict with any other properties.  (see [this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431397/how-to-define-typescript-type-as-a-dictionary-of-strings-but-with-one-numeric-i) for more info.)  For example, the type below has a problem with its `baz` member:

```
interface A {
  foo: string; // okay
  bar: number; // okay
  baz: boolean; // <-- error! boolean not assignable to string | number
  [k: string]: string | number;
}
```

The index signature `[k: string]: string | number` means "if you read a property from `A` with *any key* of type `string`, you will get a value of type `string | number`."  The `foo` property is compatible, because the key `"foo"` is a `string`, and the value type `string` is assignable to `string | number`.  The `bar` property is compatible, because the key `"bar"` is a `string`, and the value type `number` is assignable to `string | number`.  But `baz` is in error.  The key `"baz"` is a string, but it violates the index signature; `boolean` is not assignable to `string | number`.

You cannot use index signatures like the above to say "well, the property at key `"baz"` is a `boolean` but every *other* `string`-keyed property has a value of type `string | number`.  It would be nice to have a way to say that, (see [microsoft/TypeScript#17687](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867) for a request for this) but index signatures don't work that way.

It helps to think that the key `"baz"` is a special case of `string`, so its property type can be a special case of `string | number`, and `boolean` doesn't work.

---

So, let's put those together:

```
interface NotOkay {
  [x: number]: Animal; // error!  Animal not assignable to Dog
  [x: string]: Dog;
}
```

Let's say I have a value of type `NotOkay` and I index into it with one of its keys:

```
const notOkay: NotOkay = {
  str: dog,
  123: animal
}
const randomKey = Object.keys(notOkay)[Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0 : 1]; // string
const randomProp = notOkay[randomKey] // Dog?
console.log(randomProp.breed.toUpperCase()); // either LAB or runtime error?
```

This will possibly lead to a runtime error, because the key `123` is actually `"123"`, a `string`.  The `string` index signature for `NotOkay` says that every property at a `string` key will be of type `Dog`.  But wait, the `number` index signature is incompatible with that.  If I go ahead and treat every `string`-indexed property as type `Dog`, I will have problems with some of these supposed `Dog`s not having a `breed`.

So the `number` index signature is a problem for that reason. It helps to think that the key type `number` is a special case of `string`, so its property type can be a special case of `Dog`, and `Animal` doesn't work.

---

If you switch `Dog` and `Animal` around, the problem goes away:

```
interface Okay {
      [x: string]: Animal;
      [x: number]: Dog;
}
const okay: Okay = {
  str: animal,
  123: dog
}
const randomKey2 = Object.keys(okay)[Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0 : 1]; // string
const randomProp2 = okay[randomKey2] // Animal
console.log(randomProp2.name.toUpperCase()); // no error here, FIDO or FLUFFY
```

Since `number` keys are a special case of `string` keys, and `Dog` is a special case of `Animal`, everything works nicely.  Your property of unknown `string` key is known to be an `Animal`.  It's okay if you treat a `Dog` like an `Animal`, because it is one.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-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)

Comment: nice explanation! What is the reason that TS adopts this behavior since array uses number and string as index, and they should have the same type signature, so does TS check different subtypes for number index?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Arrays in TS don't have a `string` index signature.  They have a `number` index signature for the elements, and a bunch of individual sting literal indices like `length` & `push`, none of which are numeric-like strings.  If arrays had a `string` index signature then it would have to be at least as wide as the union of all the other property types... but it doesn't have one so there's no issue like this.

Comment: Your comment and this answer made perfect sense.

Comment: Nice explanation. Few minor doubts still remain. So,  while using interface Okay, we still can't access "breed" with randomProp2. Therefore, it's the same as doing SuperClass spObj = new SubClass() and access the properties of SuperClass. But, in this inheritance case, I can understand the usage that we are running the subclasses property/methods. But, in the above case, since I can't use breed property. What's the use case in having a syntax like interface Okay. Let me know, if I am clear in explaining my doubts.

Comment: @jcalz, you are right, I forgot to check the type definition for array, I thought since we can do `let a = [1,2,3]; a['0']=11` in javascript, TS will allow numeric string as index signature. But it does not seem the case.

Comment: @KenpachiZaraki In `Okay` you can access `breed` if you know you have a `number` key, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/yNa8Pw). But as for use cases, I'm not sure why someone would actually want both a `number` and `string` index... maybe an expando array like [this](https://tsplay.dev/KWz43N)?  I think the behavior of both a number-and-string index signature is not so much a design but a logical consequence of the rules for index signatures.

Comment: @jcalz . There was some abmiguity in my mind regarding the links that you have shared. In this [linkA](https://cutt.ly/rjrQ8Qv), at line 60, you haven't considered if randomProp2 can be undefined whereas in this [linkB](https://cutt.ly/EjrWhMW), at line 21/22, you have considered the case. I find the usage kinda inconsistent. Can you help me in understanding why it is happening.

Comment: That's a different issue with index signatures (and getting out of scope for this question, probably): `undefined` is not, by default, included in the domain of index signature properties even though not all keys are guaranteed present.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#13778](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778) for discussion, and see the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler flag added in TS4.1 [doc link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess) as a possible way to deal with it.