# How can I exclude some type from a key string type in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to exclude the `firstName` key from the string type of the key.

[image]

But I got the `An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'.ts(1023)` error.

**Sandbox demo:**
[codesandbox.io/s/pzo4u?file=/index.ts](https://codesandbox.io/s/pzo4u?file=/index.ts)

Comment: Please alway try to share your code in same sandbox but not as image

Comment: For me it is looks like XY problem. Your code is invalid. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @captain-yossarian https://codesandbox.io/s/pzo4u?file=/index.ts

Comment: @captain-yossarian I just want to declare a type that all the keys have the same type except some special keys.

Comment: I don't think what you are trying is possible/supported in TS (neither the type "all strings except that string", nor an index structure that excludes a few properties)

Comment: @ASDFGerte I think so, but I am not sure.

Comment: The `Omit<Type, Keys>` utility type requires a type from which you can remove certain keys (E.G. an interface). You're passing a string and that doesn't work.
See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys for futher explanation.

Comment: My approach was bad, here you have a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431397/how-to-define-typescript-type-as-a-dictionary-of-strings-but-with-one-numeric-i

Comment: Thank you for your shared useful links.
But it seems having a type like this actually is impossible.