# Typescript: Object with multiple types

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to say that everything other than 'keyA' is of type string, while 'keyA' is type string[]?

For example:

```
row: {
  [name: string]: string | string[];
  keyA: string[];
  everythingButKeyA: string[]
}
```

How do I specify the everythingButKeyA portion?

Comment: No, there is no current support for what you're doing; see [microsoft/TypeScript#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867) for the suggestion to add something like this.  Also see the [answer to the question this duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61434547/2887218) for more information and possible approached/workarounds.  Translating the code there to this question produces [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZ83Jw), which you might find useful.