# TypeScript nested object interface with known subset of keys

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, interface

I have a JavaScript object created like this.

```
const meta = {
  baz: null
}

const response = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: {
    foo: 2,
    buzz: {
      foo: 3,
      ...meta
    },
    ...meta
  },
  ...meta,
  qux: ‘qux’
}
```

The response object is a plain object that can contain any key. We know the type of keys `foo`, `baz`, and `qux`. We don’t know the other key names but when they do exist, they are objects with a known interface. In fact, the `response` object is an instance of this interface.

How do I create a TypeScript interface expressing this logic? I want the compiler to allow defining objects like this:

```
const foo: MyInterface = {
  foo: 1,
  dynamicKey: {
    baz: null
  }
}
```

Comment: Would an index signature not work? (think replacing `dynamicKey` with `[key: string]: KnownInterface`)

Comment: Index signatures might work if you are okay with [this limitation](https://tsplay.dev/wEDgOW).  Otherwise I think you want [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431397/how-to-define-typescript-type-as-a-dictionary-of-strings-but-with-one-numeric-i) where the answer is translated to be "dictionary of `MyInterface` but with a set of known keys of other types".  I can do that when I get to it.

Comment: Thanks both @jcalz, the trick was to expand the index signature interface like you showed me in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Index signatures might work if you are okay with [this limitation](https://tsplay.dev/wEDgOW).

This worked for my use case. The trick was to expand the index signature interface with all values. This has a limitation as was pointed out, but it's a much better situation than not having any type checking or autocompletion. My interface now looks like this.

```
interface MyInterface extends KnownInterface {
  [key: string]: MyInterface | KnownInterface[keyof KnownInterface];
}
```