# mapped type in typescript, how to type all other keys?

Tags: typescript, types

for a record with id(number), but all other fields are strings. How to type it?

the following definition is invalid.

```
type RecordWithID = {
  id: number;
  [key: string]: string;
};
```

ps: edit int => number

Comment: `int` is not a type in TypeScript, btw

Comment: You can try `[key: string]: string | number;`

Comment: See [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431397/how-to-define-typescript-type-as-a-dictionary-of-strings-but-with-one-numeric-i) for answers.  Good luck!