# Interface accepting any number of key value objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, interface

I have the following interface / type as shown below:

```
export interface Bar {
  title?: string;
  [key: string]: string;
}

export type Foo = {
  name: string;
} & {
  [key: string]: Bar;
};
```

And when I try to declare a variable like so:

```
const someObject: Foo = {
  name: 'John',
  city: {
    a: 'something',
  },
};
```

It gives me the error:

> Type '{ name: string; city: { a: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Foo '. Type '{ name: string; city: { a: string; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: Bar ; }'.
> Property 'title' is incompatible with index signature.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Bar'.

---

**Question**:

How to create an interface to satisfy an object like:

```
const someObject: Foo = {
  name: 'John',
  randomProperty1: { a: 'a' },
  randomProperty2: { b: 'b' },
  // any number of 'Bar'
};
```

Comment: There's no specific interface that works that way.  See the [question this duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61431397/2887218) for more information.   If I translate the code from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61434547/2887218) here, I get [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wRJVxw), which should demonstrate the possibilities and their pros/cons.