# For a given dictionary, allow a subset of its keys to attain a different value than the broader rest of the keys

Tags: typescript, dictionary, typescript-generics, union-types, mapped-types

With a given `Record<string, SomeInterface>` dictionary, I want to a union of "special" keys that can omit a specific prop from value

Here is an intuitive attempt at an implementation that unfortunately doesn't work:

```js
export type Dictionary<K extends keyof any, V> = Partial<Record<K, V>>

interface Foo { x: string }
interface Bar { x: string, y: number }

type FooKeys = 'foo1' | 'foo2'

type MixedDictionary = Dictionary<string, Bar> & Dictionary<FooKeys, Foo>

const mixedDictionary: MixedDictionary = {
  "foo1": { x: "some string" },
  "sfdds": { x: "some string", y: 23 }
}
```

Giving me the error:

```
Type '{ foo1: { x: string; }; sfdds: { x: string; y: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'MixedDictionary'.
  Type '{ foo1: { x: string; }; sfdds: { x: string; y: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<Record<string, Bar>>'.
    Property '"foo1"' is incompatible with index signature.
      Property 'y' is missing in type '{ x: string; }' but required in type 'Bar'.(2322)
```

I was expecting `{ "foo1": { x: "some string" }}` to be assignable to `MixedDictionary`, because is it assignable to `Dictionary<FooKeys, Foo>`, but somehow this isn't enough.

Is there a straight-forward way to achieve my use-case?

**[PLAYGROUND LINK HERE](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAiBLAxjDEB2AhlIgDwDScoMw+AJgM5wDWwiEAZnIfogDRwAagD44AXjgAFYrkIAbUgCVgWaHQoCRwgFDaM+GlA6EsqAGIQIcAN5wQALjgMYUfQHM4AXz0HgRk6gAQsQ2do7OrvhuAoiO+ACuALYARn5eukgocBYQ5GxMEgDkHJYAjIVwAD5wxZYATBXVtRANGcioALIYIMB0mDh4RCTi6Ni4BMRkEe4CwVCiAGSjAxMkpDl5iAwCOTraqvjOcIndvf3jQ7FwXT19Y4OTI9bacHAARCUQpW+Otg7vDAgiVQ0yib08fBeAI4dEYP1C-zegOBThc7jeMUcdQAzOlvEA)**

Comment: No, this is not directly possible.  See the [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61434547/2887218) for the various possibilities and workarounds.  If I translate that code to your question it yields [this, see in the Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w11Xkw). Good luck!