# Typescript optional intersection of types with index signature

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a type that is essentially

```
interface Type<T> {
  state: boolean;
  [id: string]: <T>;
};
```

where the `id` objects are optional, i.e. the type only requires the `state` field. However, this gives the error `Property 'isFetching' of type 'boolean' is not assignable to 'string' index type`.

After some reading, I have attempted to split up and intersect the two type separately as

```
interface TypeA {
  [id: string]: SomeOtherType;  
}

interface TypeB extends Partial<TypeA> {
  state: boolean;
};
```

which gives me `Property 'state' of type 'boolean' is not assignable to 'SomeOtherType' index type`

I can make the typescript error-free by splitting everything up like

```
type TypeA = {
  [key: string]: SomeType;  
}

type TypeB = {
 state: boolean;
}

type TypeC = Partial<TypeA> & TypeB
```

but then trying to use `TypeC` with just the `state` property I get

```
const c: TypeC = {
    state: false
}
```

`Type '{ state: false; }' is not assignable to type 'SomeType'. Type '{ state: false; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<TypeA>'. Property 'state' is incompatible with index signature. Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'SomeType | undefined'`

So it seems to forgets about my `state` Type and prioritizes my index string type, which I don't want it to do. How can I fix this?! I am at a loss

Comment: What happens when one of your objects has `state` as its id?

Comment: I'm inclined to close this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431397/how-to-define-typescript-type-as-a-dictionary-of-strings-but-with-one-numeric-i but as it stands this doesn't seem to be a [mre] of your issue, since I would expect an error in ... ugh you edited that didn't you right while I was typing.  Okay, never mind that last bit

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to make my post more clear...I am trying to get better at my StackOverflow posting

Comment: Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431397/how-to-define-typescript-type-as-a-dictionary-of-strings-but-with-one-numeric-i) and [its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61434547/2887218).  Good luck!