# how to declare types for recursive object which inclues known unknown keys

Tags: typescript, types, casting

I want to declare the type for this kind of recursive object where **name** and **link** is a mandatory field

```
{
          1: {
            name: 'Youtube',
            link: '/inventory/youtube',
            1: {
              name: 'home',
              link: '/inventory/youtube/home'
            }
          },
          2: {
            name: 'Network Infrastructure',
            link: '/inventory/network-infrastructure',
          }
}
```

I have tried to do like this but getting error (Property 'name' of type 'string' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'propTypes'),

```
type propTypes = {
    name: string;
    link: string;
    [key: string | number]: propTypes
  };
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431397/how-to-define-typescript-type-as-a-dictionary-of-strings-but-with-one-numeric-i

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NrvplN) meet your needs?  If not, please [edit] your question to make a [mre] which demonstrates a failed use case.  If it does meet your needs I can write up an answer.

Comment: Hey, @jcalz thank you very much for your help, it is working as expected :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the unknown keys are any possible string at all, then what you want isn't really possible in TypeScript at the moment.

An `string` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) like `{[key: string]: PropTypes}` means: if a property with a key of type `string` exists, then it must have a value of type `PropTypes`.  But that means the `link` and `name` properties would also need to be of type `PropTypes` and not `string` like you want.  That's where the error comes from.

You might want to say "every `string` key *except* `"link"` and `"name"` should have a value of type `PropTypes`.  But there's currently no way to express that.  There's a longstanding open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867) asking for such "hybrid" or "rest" index signatures.  Who knows when or if something like that will ever be implemented.  For now, there's no specific type in TypeScript that works this way.

There are various workarounds but they are all somewhat complicated.  See [How to define Typescript type as a dictionary of strings but with one numeric "id" property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431397/how-to-define-typescript-type-as-a-dictionary-of-strings-but-with-one-numeric-i) for an overview of the different possible approaches there.

---

However, in your case it seems that the unknown keys are specifically *numeric strings* like `"1"` or `"2"` and not arbitrary strings.  In this case, you could use a `number` index signature instead:

```
type PropTypes = {
    name: string;
    link: string;
    [key: number]: PropTypes // okay
};
```

This is all right because `"name"` and `"link"` are not numeric strings.  It's no longer a contradiction to say that the `name` and `link` properties should have `string` values, while all numeric-like properties should have `PropTypes` values.  And thus your recursive object meets this definition:

```
const prop: { [key: number]: PropTypes } = {
    1: {
        name: 'Youtube',
        link: '/inventory/youtube',
        1: {
            name: 'home',
            link: '/inventory/youtube/home'
        },
        2: {
            name: 'explore',
            link: '/inventory/youtube/explore',
            1: {
                name: 'Indias Factory Customisation',
                link: '/inventory/youtube/Indias-first-Factory-Customisation'
            },
            2: {
                name: 'YouTube Mix',
                link: '/inventory/youtube/YouTube-Mix'
            }
        }
    },
    2: {
        name: 'Network Infrastructure',
        link: '/inventory/network-infrastructure',
    }
};
```

Note that `prop` is not of type `PropTypes`, because it lacks the `name` and `link` properties.  But since each property and nested subproperty *does* have those properties, you can say that `prop` is of type `{[key: number]: PropTypes}`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAFXBAzlAvFA3gWACgoSoA7AQwFsIAuKdYOASzIHMBuI0qAG1YDW9Ri3ZdipANoCIIemQCuVAEYQ4AXXrwkqSOiIBfcUQDGCMoyhhEYerijTZ8pao1abujFAPY83UgCMdv48JJQ09ADkAJoICsAKqpEANCGh-GRCUJEA9KwAbhBkwAhwIDkgcQlJqRKhUEF+dfWk4XTZABYINClpLXyCUXlkhcWl5ZXxiRA5XT19pAa1-QBMwc39bVEQAB5gvKUQvRstGVm5BUUlZRVV0zm7+4fH-TyNBCev5NTtkQCSZAAJswKJgAGIUEzXEBQADCCkY3WY6AowGY5heX3Sg2yw1G0NuU1UOQBwNBAFoAGbMOCMckQqHjcnwxFUZGo9FkSILepLHmhNZNLGhLbZWIKZDTKAAWWYO0xwpIZyGlzGN0m1Rm4slqnJsvl-J4Bn5xuafOago+mx+UQAchBgAB3UoCKAAylwUFMBRQhRwI7LU44i4jK7jHJkB3OuACcmsD1euA+hL+hXeQwcIA)