# Typescript - Self reference with generic property

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is it possible to have a self-referenced type representation like this?

```
export type SelfReferenced {
    prop: string;
    [x: string]: SelfReferenced;
}
```

It means that all keys will be a reference of this except `prop` field
Ex:

```
const $deep: SelfReference = createProxy();
let lastReference = $deep.a.very.long.nested.deep; //type: SelfReference
lastReference.prop //type: string
```

---

Additional requirement is using generic type parameter in `prop`:

```
export type SelfReferenced<T> {
    prop: () => T;
    [x: string]: SelfReferenced<T>;
}
```

Comment: The problem I see is that `prop` key is of type string & then `[x: string]` will conflict. If you can make one of these key types something else then it'll work or I guess inherit the other part?

Comment: You can make a self reference easily, but you can't make one where the `prop` property is incompatible with all the other properties.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431397/how-to-define-typescript-type-as-a-dictionary-of-strings-but-with-one-numeric-i for various workarounds

Comment: [Here](https://tsplay.dev/WyOvxN) is the code from the answer there translated to this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be represented by intersection:

```
type SelfReferenced = {
    prop: string;
} & { [x: string]: SelfReferenced; }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhA2AzAShREBOEB2BjCAJlALxQDeAUFNVGBgPZgBcUAzsBgJbYDmA3BQC%20UAGTkoAbQAeLdl14BdFnCSp0WPIT5RBFCgQi54AQyxRc9bOygASAxGawEKNJhz4CA%20BGBQT7NTdNElt7MAA6Y3CAN0wQcPhLHnDsCHZCcLDtAHps0EhlZ0CNfAp-YGL3CHC6Rihc-IhZDm4eIA)

---

**Update:** Workaround for self-referencing recursive type with generics:

```
interface _SelfReferenced<T> { [x: string]: SelfReferenced<T>; }
type SelfReferenced<T> = _SelfReferenced<T> & { prop: () => T }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPoGUIBsYCUIzQQhIAmAPACoB8yA3sgNoAeAXMgM5hSgDmAuu0w58hKMTJVqAbmQBfAFBgAngAcUwvASIkIFGsgC8aTaJ2SDAMnrJVUAPar2ACgCUR2pXkKFpCAiw4cWQEexAuZAASPwgnZFNtcV0KBmBSdhAAVwBbACNoeRkFLAgwZECuMySkIyiY1QA6OAaAN2hlBqww3gaQCC49BvrZAHoRlXUhbC0xCQhiuErEuYa7RzcGtOQxiYgMnPyoIA)

Comment: Thanks, Things is I as trying with generic but there must be some bug which it doesn't allow to make it work deep.. like [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhA2AzAShREBOEB2BjCAJgDwAqAfFALxQDeAUFI1GBgPZgBcUAzsBgJbYA5gG46AXygAyWlADaADy68BwgLpc4SVOix5CpMiKji6dAhFzwAhlii5W2XlAAkFiJ1gIUaTDnzENPwEHNgArgC2AEaY4kZ08BDAUDa8On76VK7uYAB01rkAbpggufCOQrnYELyEuTnGAPSNoJCa3ul6+AnWab5dELks7FDNrRDKfIJCQA)

Comment: @PedroMora in linked example it is not clear what generics is used for

Comment: Let's say instead `prop: string` I have a method wich returns an `obj instanceof GenericType`

Comment: @PedroMora here's a workaround https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPoGUIBsYCUIzQQhIAmAPACoB8yA3sgNoAeAXMgM5hSgDmAuu0w58hKMTJVqAbmQBfAFBgAngAcUwvASIkIFGsgC8aTaJ2SDAMmT4EAeygUA5Kqh3VTgDTIAFAEojWhoFBVIIBCw4cWR7EC5kABIwiFUhbC0xCT1yOmBSVhAAVwBbACNoORkFLAgwZEiuM3FdI0Tk1QA6OA6AN2hlDqw7EF4OkAguPQ722QB6WZV1NJFtZqRquEbVrI7Xd38OvOR5xYh2IrLoIA