# Creating a Record type with predefined keys for types different than the rest of the Record's types

Tags: typescript

What's the canonical/idiomatic way to enforce a type like this:

```
let x:T = {
  foo: "foo",
  bar: 3
}
```

where type `T` would require there always be a `foo: string` property but require that any other properties be a `number`

This doesn't work:

```
type T = {foo: string} & Record<string, number>
```

because the first part of the intersection conflicts with the second (even though it *sort of* expresses the idea of what I want).

And for basically the same reason, neither does this (even though it really does look like the shape of what I want):

```
type T = {
  foo: string
  [index: string]: number
}
```

I can think of various complicated ways around this, with builder that would check and piece together the individual parts, but I feel there's got to be a better/easier way.

Anyway, what's the best way to do this?

Comment: You'd think there's an easier way to do it but there really isn't, unfortunately.  See the open issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867 for discussion and the [answer to the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61434547/2887218) for various approaches and workarounds.