# Object with single string property but also with index signature of other type for any other property

Tags: typescript

```
type Config = {
    [key: string]: {
        client: string,
        connection: Object,
        models: Object,
    },
    def: string;
}

const config: Config = {
    def: `mysql`,
    mysql: {
        client: "mysql",
        connection: {
            host: 'host',
            port: 'port',
            // ...
        },
        models: {}
    }
}
```

throws:

```
Property 'def' of type 'string' is not assignable to 'string' index type '{ client: string; connection: Object; models: Object; }'.
Type '{ def: string; mysql: { client: string; connection: { host: string; port: string; }; models: {}; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Config'.
  Property 'def' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ client: string; connection: Object; models: Object; }'.
```

but I need to define type where def will be string type and any other value under any possible other key will be specific object.
Any ideas how to achieve it?

Typescript playground with above example:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmUC8UDeAoKQqAbQGsIQAuKAZ2ACcUE0Bda-IzqAYwBsUICYNTqNmAGgJdC3RAgjdgKRNQDyAIwBWC4JOmEAtnAAmEXjTVadeogF8bhU0hEMmaANx5bePLIR0eRFQ0anhkdCxcKUcIZygAAwMQGgBHXniHKCTU3nZorj4BIWoAImy0kszOP3lFZQQ8-S4ACzg6agByVroOqv0wOHphKA6Bod78poB6KagAOgXJuz7DEzMLXG9Ob1sgA

Edit:

I think I know what is happening here, why this is not covered, this comment on github describes it well:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867#issuecomment-547940152

Comment: There is no specific type in TypeScript which behaves the way you want; there are various workarounds.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431397/how-to-define-typescript-type-as-a-dictionary-of-strings-but-with-one-numeric-i) and [its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61434547/2887218).  If I translate the code there to your example I get [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAv6PW), which shows the different possibilities.

Comment: I would propose, that you write your `Config` as an union: `type Config = { [key: string]: {..} | { def: string; }`

Comment: Yes, error disappear but it actually allows me to define 'def' property as an object, which is not type safe. I'm generally stunned that this is not covered, and I've just started learning ts. That's awful