# Adding dynamic properties to class with static properties

Tags: typescript, oop

I'm trying to allow dynamic properties in my TS class like so.

```
export class Finding {
  id?: number;

  title = '';

  assets?: Asset[] = [];

  createdAt = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

  [dynamicField: string]: DynamicFieldTypes;
}
```

But it gives me the following error.

> Property ‘title’ of type ‘string’ is not assignable to ‘string’ index type ‘DynamicFieldTypes’.ts(2411)
> View Problem

I assume it's because `[dynamicField: string]` overrides the types of all other properties. How do I fix that?

Inheritance doesn't fix that either

[link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAIgniAhhAlgYwGIuAGwCYAqcADsAM5QDeAUFHVAC7AAeDANFOBAEbABO1AL7VqLYgHs+DKGhyIyFLCDwoQAcyq16KPAH4AXJ0i8+AbhH1GKBjmBQAvFADkT81rryywBmQNQyDHyqagDaALoOUOFulmh8wIhMeACC0o4AsokAFgB0AGY44pIAFDCJwDkg4gDuxQCUUAD0UACMAAwddTH0IXgIyOhYuHiGAUHqYYbwSKiY2PhEpGTmgkA)

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/61431397/2887218 and there's no great approach.  If you don't think this is a duplicate and don't want to see it closed as such, please [edit] the question to clearly distinguish between them.

Comment: I usually use an intersection type for this with types.

Comment: @Behemoth what do you mean?

Comment: When using types you can create an intersection with `&` to *solve* this but it's something completely different with classes of course.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I thought. @jcalz my question is about classes, not types. It's not a duplicate

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NdAGQm) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining it; if not, what am I missing?