# Typescript: Exclude specific strings from string index signature

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
interface Link {
    href: string;
}

type MandatoryPaginationLinks = {
    [key in 'first' | 'last']: Link;
}
type OptionalPaginationLinks = {
    [key in 'prev' | 'next']: Link | null;
}
type PaginationLinks = MandatoryPaginationLinks & OptionalPaginationLinks;

type AdditionalLinks = {
    [key: string]: Link;
};

type Links = PaginationLinks & AdditionalLinks;

const links: Links = {
    self: {
        href: 'asdf'
    },
    prev: null,
    next: {
        href: '',
    },
    first: {
        href: 'asdf'
    },
    last: {
        href: 'asdf'
    }
};
```

I have a Links type.
first and last properties have to be set and must be `Link`. prev and next properties can be whether a Link or null. Optional links must have `Link` type. The problem is that Typescript sees 'first', 'last', 'prev' and 'next' as `string` so the expression is always mapped to `AdditionalLinks` type. I want to have a solution to exclude these four strings from `string` type.
For example (not working):

```
type AdditionalLinks = {
    [key: Omit<string, 'first' | 'last' | 'prev' | 'next'>]: Link;
};
```

Comment: There is no specific type in TypeScript that works this way, unfortunately.  You're looking for something like a [rest index signature as suggested in ms/TS#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867) or possibly negated types, neither of which TS supports.  `Omit` doesn't mean what you want it to mean (`Omit<string, K>` would remove *keys* of `string` like `"toUpperCase"`); you maybe mean `Exclude`, but `Exclude` only removes from unions, and `string` is not a union.

Comment: The various workarounds I know of are listed in the answer to [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431397/how-to-define-typescript-type-as-a-dictionary-of-strings-but-with-one-numeric-i)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you want is possible. But as an alternative solution you can use `symbol` instead of the `string` keys in `AdditionalLinks`.
So that ‍‍`first, last, prev, next` do not interfere with `AdditionalLinks` symbol keys.

```
type AdditionalLinks = {
    [key: symbol]: Link;
};
```

Next you can define `links` like this:

```
const links: Links = {
    [test]: {
        href: 'asdf'
    },
    prev: null,
    next: {
        href: '',
    },
    first: {
        href: 'asdf'
    },
    last: {
        href: 'asdf'
    }
};
```

You can declare a symbol:

```
const test = Symbol('test');
```

And for example you can get a symbol typed key's value like this:

```
links[test]
```