# Typescript Type with computed key and generic value, and other keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How to create a typescript with multiple keys, some of which are expressed as computed key with a generic value;

E.g.

```
{
groupName: 'Group 1',
participant1Id: {firstName: string, lastName: string, ...}
participant2Id: {firstName: string, lastName: string, ...}
...
}
```

cannot be expressed as

```
type Group<T> = {
  groupName: string;
  [key: string]: T;
};


due to **Property 'groupName' of type 'string' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'T'**
```

Comment: Is there any commonality to the "computed"/"generic" keys?  Do they all match `\`participant${number}Id\``?  Or are the completely arbitrary?  This could be the difference between "yes this is easy" or "no TS doesn't support this very well"

Comment: There isn't those are uuids.

Comment: Then the issue is discussed [in this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61431397/2887218); note the caveats around `{[k: string]: X} & {prop: Y}` mentioned there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
type Group<T> = {
  [key: string]: T;
} & { groupName: string; };
```

Comment: haha great idea, that's so funny that it's able to digest this format, but not the one it the OP. thanks @thedude

Comment: This sort of works but you will find it difficult to create a new value of type `Group<T>`; see [this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61431397/2887218) for more information.

Comment: @jcalz you are correct, this does remove the ts error but I feel it'll end up biting me in the long run. Ended up refactoring the data structure so it's no longer an issue