# Type for object with required key value pairs and additionally any other key value pairs

Tags: typescript

I am trying to declare an object which should have all keys of `MyEnum` with the value of type `EnumValue` and any other keys with `string` type value. Please see the example below.

```
enum MyEnum {
    A = 'A',
    B = 'B',
}

type EnumValue = {
    title: string;
    infoText: string;
};

type RequiredType = Record<MyEnum, EnumValue>;

const myObj = {
    A: { infoText: 'a', title: 'a title' },
    B: { infoText: 'b', title: 'b title' },
    someOtherKey: 'string value',
};
```

How to specify the type for `myObj` so it would be of type `Record<MyEnum, EnumValue>` as the required type (all enum values should be included as keys) and additionally accept `Record<string, string>` type?

Edit: also I would like to have autocompletion for all keys in that object. Is it possible by inferring properties from declared `myObj`?

Comment: There is no specific type that works this way, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/61431397/2887218 .  You can make a generic type and a helper function [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/mZZBem) instead.  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare myObj as of type myObjType

```
 type myObjType = RequiredType & Record<string,string>;
     const myObj:myObjType = {A:{infoText:'a',title:'a title'},
                              B:{infoText:'b',title:'b title'},
                               someOtherKey:'string value',};
```

Comment: This allows to add string key value pairs alongside required type, but would it be possible also to infer all properties from declared myObj so I can have autocompletion (when accessing myObj properties) as now only properties from RequiredType are show,