# Implement a dynamic lazy proxy collection class on typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, javascript-proxy

I'm trying to implement a lazy database connection collection in typescript. I'm creating a class called `DatabaseCollection` and my idea is to use a proxy to lazy load the connections (I'm using knex as connector) the class works fine in terms of node context, but Typescript says "property does not exists" and I don't know how to tell to Typescript about a dynamic properties class.

I use a workaround converting to `Record<string, Knex>` but I want to implement it properly, thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```js
const debug = true
process.env['DB_TEST_URL'] = 'mysql://root@localhost/test';

class NotImportantConnector {
    public url: string;

    constructor(url: string) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}

function dbFromURL(url: string): NotImportantConnector {
    return new NotImportantConnector(url);
}

class DatabasesCollection<T> {
    protected databases: Record<string, T> = {};

    constructor() {
        return new Proxy(this, this) as any;
    }

    get (target: DatabasesCollection<T>, name: string): T {
        if (name in target.databases) {
            return target.databases[name];
        }

        const envName = `DB_${name.replace(/[A-Z]/g, l => `_${l}`).toUpperCase()}_URL`;

        if (!process.env[envName]) {
            throw new Error(`Call to database ${name} needs ${envName} environment variable to run`);
        }

        target.databases[name] = dbFromURL(process.env[envName] as string) as T;
        return target.databases[name];
    }
}


// Not working with error Property 'test' does not exist on type 'DatabasesCollection<NotImportantConnector>'.
// const db = new DatabasesCollection<NotImportantConnector>();

// Workaround, using as 
const db = new DatabasesCollection<NotImportantConnector>() as unknown as Record<string, NotImportantConnector>;

console.log(db.test);
```

Comment: Please consider providing a self-contained [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're talking about without unrelated errors.  TypeScript by itself doesn't have `process` (that's node specific, right?) or `dbFromURL` or `Knex` in scope.  It would be helpful if you'd either define/import them (and if importing, tag the question with appropriate dependencies), or even better: replace them with native things.  Anything that makes it easier for others to get immediately to work on the issue will make it more likely you get a useful answer.

Comment: @jcalz I understand what you saying, but the question is not about run, the app works wth my workaround, indeed you can use other types instead the knex connection.

Comment: I am not talking about runtime either; I'm talking about being able to copy and paste that code into a standalone TypeScript IDE and reproduce the typing issue you're talking about.  If you [edit] the code here to be a [mre] then I'll take another look; otherwise we are at an impasse and I'll disengage to cut down on noise so as not to distract others. Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Now are minimal reproducible example, hope now you can rest comftably tonight XD

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NDdJ4N) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @,jcalz sure, does the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript isn't going to make it easy to use a `class` declaration to make `DatabasesCollection<T>` behave the way you want, which is that every instance should presumably have all the known properties of the class, plus an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) where every other property key has a value of type `T`.  But TypeScript can't directly represent this "every other property" concept; there's a longstanding open feature request for this at [microsoft/TypeScript#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867), but it's not part of the language yet. So adding an index signature to the class directly won't behave exactly as desired.  See [How to define Typescript type as a dictionary of strings but with one numeric "id" property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61431397/2887218) for various alternative approaches in general.

For your use case, it would be acceptable to make instances of `DatabasesCollection<T>` be the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the known instance type with `{[k: string]: T}` (aka `Record<string, T>`). This behaves well enough when accessing a value of that type... although it's hard to actually *produce* a value of that type in a way the compiler sees as type safe.

And that means we'll need to use something like [a type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to convince the compiler that your class constructor produces instances of that type.

To do this, I'd suggest renaming your `DatabasesCollection<T>` class out of the way to, say, `_DatabasesCollection<T>` so we can use the name `DatabasesCollection` for the name of the desired instance type (`_DatabasesCollection<T> & Record<string, T>`), and the name of the asserted class constructor.  Like this:

```
class _DatabasesCollection<T> {
  ⋯ // same impl, more or less
}

type DatabasesCollection<T> = _DatabasesCollection<T> & Record<string, T>;
const DatabasesCollection = _DatabasesCollection as new <T>() => DatabasesCollection<T>;
```

Let's test it out:

```
const db = new DatabasesCollection<NotImportantConnector>();
// const db: DatabasesCollection<NotImportantConnector>

const t = db.test;
// const t: NotImportantConnector
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?moduleResolution=99&target=99&module=199#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgKwsAdnAvnAZlCEOAIjAEMYALYgbgCg6BjCdAZ3gBMBTAIwFcA5nAC8cGFD5c6YAoy6tWAOi7oAbgG0A5ABEAQgH0AKgFEAyof0BVAEoAZTQF0RcTSACerAI4AbAFwB6fwIIGAABbwhGMm9KCHZ-GHkYTXombzIFOAA5EIBJcGgYMnQYAGEWdC5GGGhEOjg4MD4eb2BGOD4oPzh2KAwBVIbmNnE+augACk7u3v6ASjqGhqpgJWnnafoGrDodulw+dGrgFjgOHgAxAhAbWymu3x7xececmHzIWGKyiqqaqEWcCgXBgnUwlQA7tk8gUviVyuhKuMoPdvHN6Hs0hlWHB9NoKGQeBl5OVvN4-id0AAeQwAPkBMhCfy4HDOBKJrHkj2sVWgHCps3QAgANHA6c4EFhBnBhr0xv8JgsEPUlsDQVBwVwoQAFAgADzcExWrFFxrgGXN6DcCwtxTcW2wDAaAhBRrIUBdMEe+KKHJJEDJFJYNNpovQZBAXEegoEc0ehkBDWAuDgE3DkbgGDE7s9ig47OJrCVKqWQJBYOzHpBeYLnNY6nTXAcDu2TqWsvgKlUWQjXGcAAM9PoACQIRuKYFgdJyCb+dQAQQAtAAtBz+EVwbwien9kcIbxYftzRQ1SxgMBcKClYmKrBWOz96VJlMTACEjLkCmUanUXZ7kYcYtS2WSgCChSE4GMKACBRftrzJMQIDZX1iTgUdGxwSoWRxUc-17HAu2AAh0EjEo4FUd1gEJclEKBQ4jxbR0S0rXN8xQusG17JxRHOK5CFuCYP3kJQu1-NR-ybc0cRjG0cUMRi1QrIoqxgGt2PkTiAIdHYdhgNwLzgH1CULUlyWOYNxVEPFa39QNzOpcUADI4B5ZgoH5GNRTpegO0MmzWFMoNMCsoy-QCgMzJgSkpLgCCQ0Vbc-PU8K7KiizaVSBhfPOZwINCkyIqCqk3g+QpvgRJF-lpRV6ECGUWHYM4eG9fzAvs4qYU+Ip4V+ZFaSyhr4HgHieBPJJav8eqRjEV5OrKnrET+aAgA)