# Typescript access property of an enhanced object

Tags: typescript

Lets say I want to have a common type for dynamicly created objects, which always have a name property and some numerical properties. Now I would like to pass such an object around and access the numerical properties dynamically but guarded.

I was thinking of something like this:

```
type MyObject<T extends string = string> = {[P in T]:number;} & {name:string};
type MyProperty<T extends MyObject> = Exclude<keyof T, "name">;

function processValue<T extends MyObject>(enhanced:T, key:MyProperty<T>) {
    enhanced[key]; // always a number
}

const o:MyObject<"speed" | "price"> = {name:"car", speed:100, price:200};
processValue(o, "speed");
```

however typescript throws compile error

```
Argument of type 'MyObject<"speed" | "price">' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MyObject<string>'.
  Type 'MyObject<"speed" | "price">' is not assignable to type '{ [x: string]: number; }'.
    Property 'name' is incompatible with index signature.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Is there a way to modify `MyObject` or `MyProperty` so I can keep using `processValue()` function as is?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w8YGEN) meet your needs? If so I could write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That looks very promising!

Comment: Does that mean it's likely to suffice and I should write up an answer? Or do you still need to test it before you're sure and I should wait (so I don't spend time describing something I'll need to change)?

Comment: I have tested it and have your solution in use. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't make it easy to describe an object where all unknown properties are required to have a type incompatible with those of the known properties.  This is the topic of [microsoft/TypeScript#17687](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867), and there are currently only workarounds with various drawbacks.  Also see
[How to define Typescript type as a dictionary of strings but with one numeric "id" property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431397/how-to-define-typescript-type-as-a-dictionary-of-strings-but-with-one-numeric-i).

To make your code compile without error, you could write it this way:

```
type MyObject<K extends PropertyKey> =
  { [P in Exclude<K, "name">]: number; } & { name: string };

type MyProperty<T extends MyObject<keyof T>> =
  Exclude<keyof T, "name">;

function processValue<T extends MyObject<keyof T>>(enhanced: T, key: MyProperty<T>) {
  enhanced[key]; // always a number
}
```

The original didn't work because `MyObject` defaulted to `MyObject<string>`, which was equivalent to `{[k: string]: number} & {name: string}`, an impossible type to supply, since the `name` property would need to be both a `number` and a `string`.  Such an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) is one of those workarounds, but it's not a good fit here.

The fix is to forgo referring to a default `T extends MyObject`, and use a recursive [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T extends MyObject<keyof T>`.  Or, presumably, `MyObject<Exclude<keyof T, "name">`.  But it's easier to just modify `MyObject` so that it automatically excludes `"name"`, as shown above.

Now everything works as desired:

```
const o: MyObject<"speed" | "price"> = { name: "car", speed: 100, price: 200 };
processValue(o, "speed"); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-BbMtkI-kiqtynaan96o1SM1Wu1oOy+pFBiHueG8lG9tNTotliUkOtlQHwuQuAcjidgPNa5cDdckHcHulnq8Ho6voR5QDgECQaHwbzidLBWUaVUkm4sTi8QSify6xSqUg1-TGT7CCy2T0+lNxeUlzLbvdsC8gA)