# Typescript interface(object) - default type and specific attributes

Tags: typescript

Im trying to implement the following logic.
"For specific attributes, I want to set a specific option. and for all other keys (strings) fallback to another type

I got the following code:

```
interface ProcedureValue {
    value: string
    title: string
}


export interface Procedure{
    procedure_creation_time: string
    [key :string]: ProcedureValue,
}
```

Im getting the following error:

```
Type error: Property 'procedure_creation_time' of type 'string' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'ProcedureValue'.
```

I have tried the following approaches:

- Exclude type on the key
- type | and &
- extending interfaces

All of them fail.
Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Not directly, no.  There are a bunch of workarounds, none of which are great.  See the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431397/how-to-define-typescript-type-as-a-dictionary-of-strings-but-with-one-numeric-i) and its answers for more information.