# Why can I not have a generic interface WITH an optional property of a known type?

Tags: typescript

```
interface Thing {
  [ index: string ]: string | number | boolean | Thing | Array<string | number | boolean>
}

interface FooBarable extends Omit<Thing, 'foo' | 'bar'> {
  foo: string;
  bar?: string;
}

const x: FooBarable = { abc: 123, bool: true, foo: 'abc' };
```

gives me:

```
Property 'bar' of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'string | number | boolean | Thing | (string | number | boolean)[]'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAtQHNkG8BQyyA2sqACYQAeAXMgM5hTbIC6djzIOAPsiAFcAtgCNoyPiID2UgDYQ4ICWkzdlAQShQ4ATwA8nFn0GjxkmfMUA+fAF98+UJFiIUAMRkAhONpHzk1JAg5PTIAPJCwGB6GNgANMgA5DAyiVZ4hMgpUhxM2ADcmSI+APy5XFiF9vgIUiCMyLTIHlLevv4AvHjIcCIIdACMAEwAzAnScnRMAhAJ2XSJvQiJyLaFNXX0chAAdLJSWAAUVACU+UA)

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: There's no difference between `Omit<Thing, 'foo' | 'bar'>` and `Thing` (you can't make "exceptions" to an index signature).  Is it okay to add `undefined` to the list of properties in `Thing`? If so then you can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/W4VRXN).  If not then this is essentially looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61431397/2887218) which can only be supported via workarounds.  Does that fully address the question?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a type intersection rather than inheritance.

```
interface Thing {
  [ index: string ]: string | number | boolean | Thing | Array<string | number | boolean>
}

type FooBarable = Thing & {
  foo: string;
  bar?: string;
}

const x: FooBarable = { abc: 123, bool: true, foo: 'abc' };

console.log(x);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=16#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAtQHNkG8BQyyA2sqACYQAeAXMgM5hTbIC6djzIOAPsiAFcAtgCNoyPiID2UgDYQ4ICWkzdlAQShQ4ATwA8nFn0GjxkmfMUA+fAF98+MDoAOKAGIyAQnG0j5yAF4VFgAyPEJkGBkOJmwAbgiRHwB+GK4sBPt8BCkQRmRaZA8pb19-INxkOBEEOgBGACYAZgAaZGk5OiYBCDaoqToAcmqEQeRbBOzc+jkIADpZKSwACioASjigA)

This is subtle, because `type` and `interface` are mostly the same, and [interfaces are usually preferred](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Performance#preferring-interfaces-over-intersections), but this is one case where a type intersection is closer to what you want. (I believe that's a similar issue to [what's described here](https://blog.logrocket.com/types-vs-interfaces-typescript/#handling-conflicts-when-extending).)

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Thing {
  [ index: string ]: string | number | boolean | Thing | Array<string | number | boolean>
}

type FooBarable = {
  foo: string;
  bar?: string;
} & Thing

const x: FooBarable = { abc: 123, bool: true, foo: 'abc' };

console.log(x);
```

this would work, your approach didn't work because eventhough you omitted **foo** and **bar** from **Thing** interface, the interface is of type **Index Signature**, and you're extending your **FooBarable** interface along it, so it expects that all types defined in **FooBarable** to be same type of what you defined in the **Index Signature Interface** you extended.