# Type with dynamic keys and one specific key

Tags: typescript

I want to achieve this to work:

```
type ItemWithValues = Record<string, number> & {
    name: string;
};

const testItem: ItemWithValues = {
    name: 'test',
    price: 10,
    value: 25,
};
```

It says that property "name" is incompatible and the "string" is not assignable to "number", even after I defined it as a string. How to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define Typescript type as a dictionary of strings but with one numeric "id" property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431397/how-to-define-typescript-type-as-a-dictionary-of-strings-but-with-one-numeric-i)