# Typescript: Type specific string key in object, while entries at other string keys have a different type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to type an object that looks like this:

```
{
   year: number, 
   [key: string]: { ...some object here }
}
```

Unfortunately, TS doesn't allow me to do that, "year" also being a string.
Is there any way to type such an object, discriminating the particular "year" key not receiving an object as entry?

I tried like this:

```
type Test = {
    year: number;
} & {
    [key: string]: MyObject;
}
```

also tried using the following, but it won't work either:

```
type NotYear = Exclude<string, "year">
```

Comment: This is a missing feature of TS, requested at [ms/TS#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867).  See the linked q/a for more information and various workarounds.

Comment: You can find my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77585674/3459944 and if found it worked don't forget to upvote it.

Comment: @HassanJamil, I also need specific key `year: number` in my object

Comment: @Antoine so you can define your object type as you need.