# How to map key in array of objects to keys of another object type?

Tags: typescript, types

I am trying to write types for an existing API. A minimal example of the kind of type relationship I'm trying to encode is shown below.

```
const res1: res1Type = [
  {
    name: "FieldNameA",
    value: 123
  },
  {
    name: "FieldNameB",
    value: 123
  }
];
const res2: res2Type = {
  AlwaysPresent1: "test",
  AlwaysPresent2: 1,
  FieldNameA: {
    field1: 1,
    field2: 2
  },
  FieldNameB: {
    field1: 1,
    field2: 2
  }
};

type res1Type = {
  name: string;
  value: number;
}[];
type res2Type = {
  AlwaysPresent1: string;
  AlwaysPresent2: number;
  [k: string]: subType | string | number;
};
type subType = {
  field1: number;
  field2: number;
};
```

res1 is an array of arbitrary length and the name field from each entry in the array of objects maps to a field in res2 (which has a few extra fields that are always present). These mapped fields have an object property. I've managed to used an indexed signature to describe these types but this requires me to make it a Union type:

```
[k: string]: subType | string | number;
```

Is there a way to more explicitly map the fields in res1 to fields in res2? Is there an alternative to index signatures which allow me to define an arbitrary amount of string:subType fields?

UPDATE

Implemented the approach suggested by jcalz with a small change to explicitly make res1Type Readonly.

```
type Res1Type = Readonly<{
    name: string;
    value: number;
}[]>;
```

Comment: You can use generics, possibly as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WJBAZW). Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, I'm getting some errors implementing the approach in your playground link to my project, any ideas why it's throwing errors for me but not in the playground? See the update in question.

Comment: Without a [mre] I don't know what to say to followup questions like this. There's not supposed to be an index signature so maybe you forgot `as const satisfies` somewhere? If you remove your edit, I'm happy to write up my answer as-is and if you can't debug your own issue you can open a new question.  Or you can leave it like this but also provide a [mre], and maybe I can help... with the caveat that we can't do that too many times or else the scope of the question will expand into a one-on-one tech support session which is not appropriate for Stack Overflow. How would you like to proceed?

Comment: @jcalz, I managed to solve my issue by making res1Type Readonly (updated my question). I'm not sure why I needed to do this to silence the ts error in my environment, but not in the playground. As for the answer, if you write it up I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: You're probably not using the latest version of TS; I generally presume questions are using the latest TS release and `--strict` (although sometimes that presumption turns out to be incorrect).  Anyway I'll write up an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way for `Res2Type` to know about the particular [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of `name` properties of the elements of `res1` is for you to make it [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type of `res1` or some related type.  Here's one way to write it:

```
type Res2Type<T extends Res1Type> = {
    AlwaysPresent1: string;
    AlwaysPresent2: number;
} & Record<T[number]["name"], SubType>
```

So we want `res2` to be of type `Res2Type<typeof res1>` using the [TS `typeof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html):

---

But we need to be careful.  If you just [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) `res1` as being of type `Res1Type`, like

```
const res1: Res1Type = [ ⋯ ];
```

then the type of that variable will be *widened* to `Res1Type` and forget anything specific about the initializer expression.  And that would mean that `res2` would be of type `Res2Type<Res1Type>` looks like `{ AP1: string; AP2: string} & {[k: string]: SubType }`, an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) which is hard to use (see [How to define Typescript type as a dictionary of strings but with one numeric "id" property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61431397/2887218) for a discussion about such a type) and doesn't actually constrain the keys of `res2` at all.

Instead of annotating, we should use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) to checking the inferred type of the initializer against `Res1Type` without widening it:

```
const res1 = [ ⋯ ] satisfies Res1Type;
```

Except we *still* need to be careful, because the inferred type of the `name` properties will still be `string`.  An object like `{name: "xxx"}` is inferred to be of type `{name: string}` and not `{name: "xxx"}`.  If we want the latter we need to give the compiler a hint that we care about the literal types.  The easiest way is to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on the expression:

```
const res1 = [ ⋯ ] as const satisfies Res1Type;
```

And *that* is enough to make it work.

---

So, let's see what we get:

```
const res1 = [
    {
        name: "FieldNameA",
        value: 123
    },
    {
        name: "FieldNameB",
        value: 123
    }
] as const satisfies Res1Type;
/* const res1: [{
    readonly name: "FieldNameA";
    readonly value: 123;
}, {
    readonly name: "FieldNameB";
    readonly value: 123;
}] */
```

That compiles without error (in TS5.3+) and you can see it keeps track of `"FieldNameA"` and `"FieldNameB"`.  So the type we want for `res2` is

```
type R2Test = Res2Type<typeof res1>;
/* type R2Test = {
    AlwaysPresent1: string;
    AlwaysPresent2: number;
} & Record<"FieldNameA" | "FieldNameB", SubType> */
```

If you want you can annotate `res2` with that type:

```
const res2: Res2Type<typeof res1> = {
    AlwaysPresent1: "test",
    AlwaysPresent2: 1,
    FieldNameA: {
        field1: 1,
        field2: 2
    },
    FieldNameB: {
        field1: 1,
        field2: 2
    }
}; // okay
```

or you could continue using `as const satisfies` instead, depending on your later needs:

```
const res2 = {
    AlwaysPresent1: "test",
    AlwaysPresent2: 1,
    FieldNameA: {
        field1: 1,
        field2: 2
    },
    FieldNameB: {
        field1: 1,
        field2: 2
    }
} as const satisfies Res2Type<typeof res1>; // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-JCOhUugnu9Gha3UWJ4ctuolonWIALckZkOyUIJaywq1suXs6zx+NvhDt7buD8f9gKK8fDvznZhQGo1KCKADW8OzTTyLU88qhforTarWxrwDrDYDQcSY529in+l7s+nw0XKQfPMnCvnyvvd9tUoEcUnODIshzPJ4AKIolTteB3kgL40CLFpECBHAgA)

Res2Type

```
type Res1Type = {
    name: string;
    value: number;
}[];

const res1 = [
    {
        name: "FieldNameA",
        value: 123
    },
    {
        name: "FieldNameB",
        value: 123
    }
] as const satisfies Res1Type;


type SubType = {
    field1: number;
    field2: number;
};
```