# How to write generic data types with typescript for string

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

In my object, have different `key` for each of the object. for that how to write generic data type?

here is my try:

```
interface Dic {
    [key:string]:string; // how to write for generic values
    age:number;
}

const Object1:Dic = {
        name:"name1",
        age:0
}

const Object2:Dic = {
        village:"name1",
        age:40
}
```

For me it's throws the error. any one help me to understand this kind of scenarios?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript Interface, enforce the type of extra properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44358611/typescript-interface-enforce-the-type-of-extra-properties)

Comment: [Another duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431397/how-to-define-typescript-type-as-a-dictionary-of-strings-but-with-one-numeric-i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `age:any;` or `[key:string]:any;`.

Unfortunately in the typescript interface the dynamic property needs to be abstract enough to contain all non-dynamic properties .